# Not able to fetch URLs from a column(Images URLs are saved in a column)in spreadsheet and create PDFs using urlfetchapp in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet in which I have image urls saved in a column(column H), I am trying to create PDFs  by fetching URLs from column and fetch the image stored to create my PDF

Here is my code

```
function createBulkPdf() {
  var TEMPLATE_ID = '<<Template_id>>';
  var PDF_FILE_NAME = '<<PDF folder id>>';
  const copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID);
  const folderFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(PDF_FILE_NAME);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastrow);
  const data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastrow, 8).getValues();
  var i = 2;
  data.forEach(row => {
    var url = createPdf(copyFile, folderFile, row);
    sheet.getRange(i, 8).setValue(url);
    Logger.log(i);
    i = i + 1;
  });
}

function createPdf(copyFile, folderFile, data) {
  const copyfilenew = copyFile.makeCopy(folderFile);
  const copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyfilenew.getId());
  const body = copyDoc.getBody();
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(data[7]); //data[7] represents column H
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
  var next = body.findText("{al}");
  var r = next.getElement();
  r.asText().setText("");
  var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp.getBlob());
  img.setWidth(100);
  img.setHeight(80);

  body.replaceText("{b}", data[1]); //body.toString().replaceText("{b}",b);
  body.replaceText("{c}", data[2]);
  body.replaceText("{d}", data[3]);
  body.replaceText("{e}", data[4]);
  body.replaceText("{f}", data[5]);
  body.replaceText("{g}", data[6]);

  copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  const newpdffile = copyfilenew.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var docid = folderFile.createFile(newpdffile).setName(data[3]).getId();
  var filelink = "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + docid;
  Logger.log(filelink);
  folderFile.removeFile(copyfilenew);
  return filelink;
}
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: This `const data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastrow, 8).getValues();` should this `const data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastrow-1, 8).getValues();`

Comment: The error is in "var resp=urlfetchapp.fetch(data[7]);" line, its say urfetchapp no value error

Comment: How does your `data` look like? Also please bear in mind that `getValues` returns a two-dimensional array. @KumarAbhishek

Comment: its a survey data with few questions and tthe survey's photo and signature of interviewee for each interview is saved as hyperlinks in column H

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` in order check exactly how does it look like? Or can you share some additional information regarding this? @KumarAbhishek